# How to extract top five values in excel using index, match, and large

Tags: excel

How do I extract the top five values in an excel column? This is what I have so far:

```
=INDEX($E$3:$E$143,MATCH(1,INDEX(($AH$3:$AH$143=LARGE($AH$3:$AH$143,ROWS(AJ$28:AJ28)))*(COUNTIF(AJ$28:AJ28,$E$3:$E$143)=0),),0))
```

table

```
Customer name    Contract Date     Contract age                   Oldest Cotracts

Bill              8/1/18             5                               bill
John              8/2/18             4                               john
David             8/3/18             3                               David
```

The formula i have above is in the cell to the right where bill's name is. But it is not taking into consideration ties and is populating "N/A'

Comment: It would be easier if you mocked up some data similar to yours, only including the columns that are needed, with the desired outcome.  Pleas [edit] your post to include a minimal example of your data.

Comment: scott i have been a member for all of 5 minutes lol. I may need some help doing that

Comment: this excel sheet keeps track of contracts and how old they are. I have a column that populates how old the contract is based off the date of said contract. I need to extact the five oldest contracts and list them from oldest to newest but this formula is not considering contracts that are the same age

Comment: create it in Excel.  copy and paste the values in the post using [edit].  High light the table and hit ctrl-K.  If you have problems do the copy and paste and save the edits, someone will help format the table correctly.

Comment: You might start be reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: scott, when i copy and past it doesnt show the gridlines

Comment: and it won't we do not care about those.  Your table should only have the needed info.  Do not add any columns not germane to the question.

Comment: use [edit] to put the new data in the original post, not the comments.

Comment: sorry man i cannot figure this out.

Comment: create the table in excel.  copy and paste all the data at one time, so the data shows up in the edit as a small table, not one column.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a column that retreives the top five contract age using LARGE:

```
=LARGE(C:C,ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

Then refering to that you would use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$19)/($C$2:$C$19=E2),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2)))
```

[image]

with older version of Excel use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$19=E2,ROW($C$2:$C$19)),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with  Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: so what would the whole formula look like scott? thank you for the help by the way

Comment: It can't be done in one formula, when there are duplicates.  Hence the need for the helper column.

Comment: nevermind on the previous comment. I get it now. One question though. after aggregate what does the 15 and 6 represent?

Comment: 15 is "SMALL" and 6 is "IGNORE ERRORS"

Comment: GETTING A #NAME? error

Comment: I assume then you are using 2007 excel or earlier.  This formula will not work in earlier versions.

Comment: yea I am using 2007

Comment: will an update help?

Comment: now it isnt going from oldest to newest

Comment: CAN I COPY AND PASTE AN ARRAY FORMULA DOWN